# australian emails ok USA emails bouncing

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Using Outlook I send 10 emails per day with 50 addresses in the BCC area.
When sending to Australian addresses I had no trouble. Now I am trying to send to addresses in USA - sourced the same way as the Australian addresses.
However, with these USA addresses I am getting an absolutely huge number of bounced emails.
What could cause this?

Mike

Comment: What does the bounce message say? Maybe the addresses are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The reason or error code/message in the bounce message is the key to resolve this issue. Some [codes in non-delivery report](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/exchange/guides/ExMgmtGuide/fb7830cf-23c6-48a6-8759-526b7854ae39.mspx?mfr=true) for your reference.

How about sending the emails from web mail in browsers? If you experience the same issue when sending from web mail, the issue might be the mail system related. Contact your mail system admin for assistant. However, the content of the bounce message is still the key point.